# Counting occurrences using n-grams

Tags: moving-window, sequential-pattern-mining

I was asked to do the following exercise:

Consider the sequence

> IROIRDXMIRDOMORIORMTDMMDMWBIRQGDM

Count the number of occurences of `IRDM` using:

- n-grams
- minimal window
- windows of size 6

I believe the result is 3 occurrences of minimal window and 5 occurrences for windows of size 6. But I don't know what n-gram means in this case.

From what I understand the n-grams of `IRDM` are:

```
I, R, D, M, IR, RD, DM, IRD, RDM, IRDM
```

Am I supposed to count the occurrences of all the n-grams?

In that case I get this result:

```
occ(I)= 5
occ(R)= 6
occ(D)= 5
occ(M)= 7
occ(IR)= 4
occ(RD)= 2
occ(DM)= 3
occ(IRD)= 2
occ(RDM)= 0
occ(IRDM)= 0
```

But I don't know if this is what I should be doing. Any idea to what this could mean given the context?